# How to get text from multiple textboxes controls another program. C# WM_GETTEXT

Tags: c#

I'm trying to grab text from multiple or specific textboxes / controls in another application.

The code I have here works, it displays the textbox text into label2.text.

BUT it's not reading the value from the textbox I need. All the textboxes class names are " WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.141b42a_r12_ad1 ". So how do I read specific boxes?

Also note, the handle changes everytime the application is re-opened. But class name doesn't.

A sample would be nice if there are any solutions.

Thanks

```
IntPtr Hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Software - Name");

IntPtr Handle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100);

int NumText = (int)SendMessage(Hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)50, Handle);


string Text = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Handle);
label1.Text = Text;

IntPtr ChildHandle = FindWindowEx(Hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.141b42a_r12_ad1", "");

IntPtr Hndl = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(200);


                NumText = (int)SendMessage(ChildHandle, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)200, Hndl);

            Text = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Hndl);

                    label2.Text = Text;
```

Comment: These window class names are auto-generated and change every time the program runs.  So you can't use them to identify the textbox you want to hit.  The location of the box relative from its parent is usually the next best approach.  But don't do this, use System.Windows.Automation instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most programs the controls are always laid out in the same z-order. So you could list all textboxes, number them by their z-order, and then use it to find it again.

This code snippet will put the contents of all textboxes into label2.

```
IntPtr Hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Software - Name");

IntPtr Handle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100);

int NumText = (int)SendMessage(Hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)50, Handle);

string Text = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Handle);
label1.Text = Text;

IntPtr ChildHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

label2.Text = "";

// Loop through all the textboxes that are children of Hwnd.
int childNo = 0;
while ((ChildHandle = FindWindowEx(Hwnd, ChildHandle, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.141b42a_r12_ad1", "")) != IntPtr.Zero) {
    IntPtr Hndl = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(200);

    NumText = (int)SendMessage(ChildHandle, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)200, Hndl);
    Text = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Hndl);
    label2.Text += "(Child Number " + childNo + ") " + Text + Environment.NewLine;
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Hndl);

    childNo++;
}
```

Once you have figured out which number your desired textbox has, you can change the code such that it only reads the text from that textbox. Say, the number is 5, you can change the while loop like this:

```
while ((ChildHandle = FindWindowEx(Hwnd, ChildHandle, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.141b42a_r12_ad1", "")) != IntPtr.Zero) {
    if (childNo == 5) {
        IntPtr Hndl = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(200);

        NumText = (int)SendMessage(ChildHandle, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)200, Hndl);
        Text = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Hndl);
        label2.Text = Text;
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Hndl);
        break;
    }

    childNo++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing to use is the control **id**. You can use Spy++ to get that.

With the program executing, go to Visual Studio. In the "Tools" menu is "Spy++". If your system is a 64-bit system then you need to use the 64-bit version of Spy++ or for 32-bit use the 32-bit version. Go to "Search" | "Find Window...". That will open a "Find Window" dialog. Now first, ensure that the program is visible; at least the relevant button part of it. Then click on the "Finder Tool" icon (the square with a circle in it that looks like a target). With the mouse button down, drag from the Finder Tool icon to the "=" button and release the mouse. The Find Window dialog will be filled in with the button's handle and other data. Click on "OK". You will then get a "Window Properties" window with a tab control with 5 tabs. The five tabs are General, Styles, Windows, Class and Process. Look for "Control ID" near the bottom of the first (General) tab. It is a hexadecimal value. Whatever the value is, it will probably be that value every time you execute that program. At the Windows API level, controls are often identified by a control id. We can use the Control ID shown in the Window Properties window in our program.

You will need the following:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetDlgItem(IntPtr hWnd, int nIDDlgItem);
```

Assuming that "handle" is the main window handle and "TextBoxId" is the id of the textbox, you can use the following to get the handle of the textbox:

```
IntPtr TextBoxhWnd = GetDlgItem(handle, TextBoxId);
```

Also see my [Clicking a Button in Another Application](http://simplesamples.info/CSharp/ClickingAButtonInAnotherApplication.aspx).

Comment: the control id is changing each time the program is run

Comment: That is unfortunate. Usually it does not but that can happen.